# So getting syntax error one my program

Tags: java

I have this program and this is one of my methods. However I have a syntax error and its saying that a throw is expected but I don't want to add a throw..how do I fix this?

```
public static void enterID(int[] list, int size){
    System.out.println("Enter Employee ID#");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      int hours = input.nextInt();
      list[i] = hours; 
      if(hours < 0)||(hours > 40); //throwsException
      { 
        System.out.println("INVALID! Should be positive. REENTER: ");
        list[i] = input.nextInt();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: so this line: if(hours < 0)||(hours > 40);

Comment: that is where the syntax error is

Comment: Voting to close this question as a simple typographical error.

Comment: I changed it to that and java is still giving me that error

Comment: If you changed it, then show us -- else how can we guess how you've changed it? You shouldn't have a semicolon at the end of the if line either.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
if(hours < 0)||(hours > 40);
```

Which should be

```
if(hours < 0 || hours > 40){
    //code here
}
```

Putting a ; at the end of your `if` statement wouldn't allow the block of code that should be in the if statement to be executed properly. Also, `if(hours < 0)||(hours > 40)` is an invalid syntax and should be `if(hours < 0 || hours > 40)`

The correct method looks like this:

```
public static void enterID(int[] list, int size){
    System.out.println("Enter Employee ID#");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      int hours = input.nextInt();
      list[i] = hours; 
      if(hours < 0 || hours > 40)
      { 
        System.out.println("INVALID! Should be positive. REENTER: ");
        list[i] = input.nextInt();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove the semicolon ; in if

```
 if(hours < 0)||(hours > 40);
```

to

```
     if(hours < 0)||(hours > 40)
      { 
        System.out.println("INVALID! Should be positive. REENTER: ");
        list[i] = input.nextInt();
      }
```